# Can´t access xml data when inside xsl-varible for-each loop

Tags: xslt, saxon

When using xsl-varible in a for-each loop I can´t access xml data with x-path normaly (it loops ok).
When trying to access the same data outside the loop there is no problem.

Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="teams">
        <team name="Team one" cg_id="155370" homepage="http://www.teamone.com" enabled="true" />
        <team name="Team two" cg_id="430906" homepage="http://www.teamtwo.com" enabled="true" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='teams']/team[@active='true']">

    <xsl:value-of select="/DATA/ITEMS/ITEM/HEADERTXT" />

</xsl:for-each>
```

I´m using saxon-he 9.3.0.5 (Kernow 1.7.2)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Well the path `/` selects the root node (document node) of the current context node. As you work with two documents it seems, the primary input document as well as the stylesheet document, and you use the `for-each` to access nodes in the stylesheet document, you need to store the main document outside the `for-each` e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="primary-doc" select="/"/>
```

then inside the for-each you can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="$primary-doc/DATA/ITEMS/ITEM/HEADERTXT" />
```

So that is an explanation why your code does not do what you want and how to fix the problem of working with several documents.

However the whole approach of using a variable with nodes but then to access it with `document('')` looks rather odd, if you have a variable `$teams` with a temporary document (which you do in XSLT 2.0) you can simply do

```
<xsl:for-each select="$teams/team[@active='true']">
  <xsl:value-of select="$primary-doc/DATA/ITEMS/ITEM/HEADERTXT"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Of course with two documents you need to make sure you store the other than as already shown in a variable outside of the for-each changing the context node and document.