# Iterate over temporary document using xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm trying to create a temporary document containing some data, so I don't have it scattered all over the xsl file.  I'm trying to loop through this data in the following manner:

```
<xsl:variable name="stuff">
  <foo name="bar" key="83"/>
  <foo name="baz" key="73"/>
  <foo name="qux" key="71"/>
  <foo name="quux" key="72"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="$stuff/foo" >
  <xsl:value-of select="@key" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

The for-each block is never entered.  I've tried to mimic the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803868).  I also looked into using node-set(), but as far as I can tell that function is only required for XSLT version 1.0?

Comment: The snippet you have posted looks fine to me, assuming an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9, AltovaXML, XmlPrime. If you continue to have problems then consider to tell us details of the environment you have and provide minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I tried reproducing my troubles using the latest version of Saxon on the command line and both of these approaches work just fine.  At least now I'm confident that the mistake isn't in the xsl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim C gave a complete answer about this in the following thread: [Use a xsl:for-each over an xml to decide which label-value pairs are displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973359/use-a-xslfor-each-over-an-xml-to-decide-which-label-value-pairs-are-displayed). I suggest you have a look at it.

Basically for **XSLT 2.0** you can include the XML which you entered now into a `<xsl:variable>` directly into your XSLT:

```
<my:stuff>
  <foo name="bar" key="83"/>
  <foo name="baz" key="73"/>
  <foo name="qux" key="71"/>
  <foo name="quux" key="72"/>
 </my:stuff>
```

Then in your XSLT where needed declare a variable:

```
 <xsl:variable name="stuff" select="document('')/*/my:stuff" />
```

So the XSLT will be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
    <my:stuff>
        <foo name="bar" key="83"/>
        <foo name="baz" key="73"/>
        <foo name="qux" key="71"/>
        <foo name="quux" key="72"/>
    </my:stuff>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="stuff" select="document('')/*/my:stuff"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$stuff/foo">
                <xsl:value-of select="@key" />
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I get an error on this line: `<xsl:variable name="stuff" select="document('')/*/my:stuff"/>`

Comment: It works fine when I try it at [xsltcake](http://www.xsltcake.com/), but not where I need it to run.  The xslt processor I'm using is Saxon, should this matter?

Comment: @expez: Unfortunally I am not familar with all the differences between the XSLT processors. Hopefully someone else could answer that..

Comment: @expez, which error exactly do you get? And how do you load the stylesheet? But I don't see why you would need to use the `document('')` approach with an XSLT 2.0 processor, your posted code looks fine for XSLT 2.0.